# Facebook Register plugin issue

Tags: facebook

I've seen many websites with the Facebook Register plugin error:

> Unable to load the registration form for [app name]. You may have
>   previously blocked this app on Facebook. Go to your Facebook privacy
>   settings to unblock this app. **(Error: 404)**

I know that Facebook Register plugin will stop working on July 30, 2015 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/v2.3).

Does anybody know why there is 404 error?

Comment: _“Does anybody know why there is 404 error?”_ – because that is the _API error code_ Facebook has assigned to it. It has nothing to do with an _HTTP status code_ 404, if that’s what you’re thinking …

Answer (score 2):

I share the answer of facebook team:

Subeesh Basheer ·  · Facebook Team

Hi Diego, your page appears to be using the Registration Plugin here:

http://2x1.co/signup/facebook

This plugin was part of API v1.0 and has been removed as part the removal of v1.0 on 30th April 2015.

You should instead use Facebook Login to authenticate users to your app, either using the Login Button or by making API calls with the Javascript SDK. The docs for these are linked below. Hope this helps.

Login flow for web: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3

---

Unable to load the registration form for 2x1.co. You may have previously blocked this app on Facebook. Go to your Facebook privacy settings to unblock this app. (Error: 404)

No se puede cargar el formulario de registro para 2x1.co. Quizá hayas bloqueado esta aplicación en Facebook con anterioridad. Ve a tu configuración de privacidad de Facebook para desbloquear esta aplicación.(Error: 404)